# add pid value to /proc/"pid"/stat

Tags: c, cpu-usage, pid

hi i need to add the pid number to /proc/%d/stat

how i can do that ?
this is my full code , with this i have the total cpu usage :

```
unsigned sleep(unsigned sec);    
struct cpustat {
    unsigned long t_user;
    unsigned long t_nice;
    unsigned long t_system;
    unsigned long t_idle;
    unsigned long t_iowait;
    unsigned long t_irq;
    unsigned long t_softirq;
};


void skip_lines(FILE *fp, int numlines)
{
    int cnt = 0;
    char ch;
    while((cnt < numlines) && ((ch = getc(fp)) != EOF))
    {
        if (ch == '\n')
            cnt++;
    }
    return;
}


void get_stats(struct cpustat *st, int cpunum)
{
    FILE *fp = fopen("/proc/stat", "r");
    int lskip = cpunum+1;
     skip_lines(fp, lskip);
    char cpun[255];
```

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, to replace the `%d` with an integer, you'll need to use `sprintf` into a buffer as you do in your second example.  You could also just use `/proc/self/stat` to get the stats of the current process, rather than getpid+sprintf.

Your main problem seems to be with the contents/format you're expecting to see.  `stat` contains a single line of info about the process, as described in proc(5).  For example:

```
$ cat /proc/self/stat
27646 (cat) R 3284 27646 3284 34835 27646 4194304 86 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 20 0 1 0 163223159 7618560 210 18446744073709551615 4194304 4240236 140730092885472 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 17 1 0 0 2 0 0 6340112 6341364 37523456 140730092888335 140730092888355 140730092888355 140730092892143 0
```

You seem to be skipping some initial lines, and then trying to read something with a different format.

---

from the proc(5) man page, some of those numbers from /proc/self/stat are related to cpu time:

```
          (14) utime  %lu
                    Amount of time that this process has been scheduled in  user  mode,  mea‐
                    sured  in  clock  ticks  (divide by sysconf(_SC_CLK_TCK)).  This includes
                    guest time, guest_time (time spent running a virtual CPU, see below),  so
                    that  applications that are not aware of the guest time field do not lose
                    that time from their calculations.

          (15) stime  %lu
                    Amount of time that this process has been scheduled in kernel mode,  mea‐
                    sured in clock ticks (divide by sysconf(_SC_CLK_TCK)).
```

Which gives you the total cpu time in this process since it started.  With the above `cat` program, those numbers are both 0 (it runs too fast to accumulate any ticks), but if I do

```
$ cat /proc/$$/stat
3284 (bash) S 2979 3284 3284 34835 12764 4194304 71122 947545 36 4525 104 66 1930 916 20 0 1 0 6160 24752128 1448 18446744073709551615 4194304 5192964 140726761267456 0 0 0 65536 3670020 1266777851 1 0 0 17 1 0 0 68 0 0 7290352 7326856 30253056 140726761273517 140726761273522 140726761273522 140726761275374 0
```

you can see that my shell has 104 ticks of user time and 66 ticks of system time.

Comment: ohhh thank you sir for the solution , i just see the information on /proc/stat  not same on /proc/self/stat , how a can get the cpu usage of  self process !?